# Is it true that $\min\{h, f_n\}\to h$ in measure provided $f_n\to f$ in measure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be a measurable set with finite measure. $\{f_n\}$ and $f$ are non-negative measurable functions on $E$, s.t. $f_n\to f$ in measure on $E$. If $h$ is a measurable, non-negative, bounded function on $E$ s.t. $0\le h(x)\le f(x)$ for all $x\in E$, is it true that $\min\{h, f_n\}\to h$ in measure on $E$?

Motivation for this question: I want to show that Fatou's Lemma is still true if the hypothsis "a.e. convergence" is replaced by "convergence in measure". I know a classical proof is to assume the contrary. But I wonder if it can be proved by modifying the proof for "a.e. convergence". But when repeating the proof I have to prove the above claim.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the claim is correct. Let $\epsilon >0$

$$h(x) - \min\{h(x), f_n(x)\} > \epsilon \; \implies \; f_n(x) < h(x) - \epsilon\le f(x) - \epsilon\; \implies f(x) - f_n(x) > \epsilon.$$

Can you finish the proof?

Comment: Thanks, this is a concise proof.

Answer (score 2):

The claim is correct.

Lemma: $f_n \to f$ in measure as $n \to \infty$ if and only if, for every given subsequence $\{n_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$, there is a subsubsequence $\{n_{k_l}\}_{l=1}^{\infty}$ such that $f_{n_{k_l}} \to f$ in measure.

The lemma is immediately proved by contradiction.

Let a subsequence $\{n_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ be given. We know that $f_{n_k} \to f$ in measure as $k \to \infty$. Choose subsubsequence $\{n_{k_l}\}_{l=1}^{\infty}$ such that $f_{n_{k_l}} \to f$ almost surely as $l \to \infty$. We see that, almost surely (and in particular in measure), $\min(h,f_{n_{k_l}}) \to h$ as $l \to \infty$. Therefore, $\min(h,f_{n}) \to h$ in measure as $n \to \infty$.

Comment: +1. I think there was an obvious error in the Lemma and I have corrected it. Please tell me if I have messed it up. I can restore the old version if needed.

Comment: Thanks. I think it should be "a.e." in the Lemma. The proof of the Lemma: $\implies$ Every subsequence of $\{f_n\}$ also converges in measure, and hence this subsequence has a sub-subsequence that pointwise converges to $f$ a.e. $x\in E$ . $\impliedby$ Assume the contrary. If $f_n\not\to f$ in measure, then $\exists$ $\sigma_0, \epsilon_0>0$ and a subsequence $f_{n_k}$ s.t. $\forall k$ $m(\{x\in E:|f_{n_k}(x)-f(x)|>\sigma_0\})>\epsilon_0$. Then every sub-subsequence of $f_{n_k}$ does not converge to $f$ in measure, and can not converge to $f$ a.e. $x\in E$.

Comment: @geetha290krm I confess it is not appropriate to ask it in that comment... But do you know why Youem's answer has a downvote? I think it is correct.

Comment: @Asigan Very seriously $f_{n_{k_l}}$ tends to $f$ in measure. This is because the subsequence $n_k$'s is arbitrarily given and there is no guarantee for almost sure convergence. I believe Youem's answer is correct too but someone just gives him a downvote. (maybe because his answer is not as complete as mine?)

Comment: I think both two statements “… s.t. $f_{n_{k_l}} \to f$ in measure and “… s.t. $f_{n_{k_l}} \to f$ a.e. $x\in E$ are correct, and can be used to prove the problem. But the latter one can give an easier proof

Comment: Your answer is quite helpful. But I am sorry that I will accept Youem’s answer, because Youem’s answer is easier to understand. Your proof is quite inspiring. But the theorem you quoted itself is not very trivial, and it to some extent “overkill” the problem.